# Martelo de ouro - Ao editar lista de duplicatas os itens adicionados não somem da busca

Tags: bug, perguntas-duplicadas, tag-ouro

Quando se tem a medalha de ouro em uma tag é possível fechar uma pergunta como duplicata de outra e posteriormente adicionar mais perguntas que a atual seria duplicata, no entanto quando estou adicionando os links notei que eles não somem da listagem:

[image: busca]

Esses dois contornados de vermelho são os mesmos, eu acidentalmente tentei adicionar duas vezes a mesma pergunta, isso porque não notei que era a mesma, acredito que para uma melhor experiencia o que já foi adicionado não deveria ser mostrado nessa busca.

---

Pra quem não sabe o que é **martelo de ouro**, ele é uma referencia aos usuários que tem pontuação elevada em uma tag especifica e com isto ganharam a [medalha de ouro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=gold), após ganhar ela é possível fechar uma pergunta como duplicata de outra sem precisar da triagem ou de outros votos (a tag na pergunta tem que ter sido adicionada por outra pessoa).

[image: martelo de ouro]

Comment: Vai sonhando rs

Comment: @bfavaretto what?

Comment: Nessa lista (autocompletar) eu duvido que eles retirem o que já estiver cadastrado como dup. Podem impedir de inserir o mesmo link 2x, isso sim – se é que já não fazem, não testei.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim eles impedem de adicionar duas vezes... uma UX meio pobre :) . Paciencia, de qualquer maneira deixo o pedido aqui.

Comment: Faz um plugin, @guilhermenascimento

Comment: @WallaceMaxters poh pior que é uma otima ideia kkkkkkk XD e é totalmente possivel :D